# Regular expression that matches two words separated by comma and space

Tags: regex, sed

I want to modify a line that contains an array of strings using sed.

myconf.yml

```
abc:
  - drop:
      fields: ["agent", "log", "input", "ecs", "message"]
```

I want to remove `"message"` from the array,

so I tried some regular expressions that replace `"ecs", "message"` to `"ecs"`

```
sed 's/"ecs",\s+"message"/"ecs"/' myconf.yml
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Try something like: `sed -E '/^[[:space:]]+fields:/s/"ecs", "message"/"ecs"/g' file` once?

Comment: Use `sed 's/"ecs",[[:space:]]*"message"/"ecs"/' myconf.yml`